# Strange output with Java switch

Tags: java, switch-statement

Please read the following function:

```
public static int getValue(int i) {
    int result = 0;
    switch (i) {
        case 1:
            result = result + i;
        case 2:
            result = result + i * 2;
        case 3:
            result = result + i * 3;
    }
    return result;
}
```

When `i = 2`, what is the output? I think it is 4, but the answer is 10 by execution. Why does this happen? Why does case 3 also execute? `i` is 2, not 3. I'm trying to think about it but I still don't know why this happens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `break` to avoid next case execution.

```
public static int getValue(int i) {
        int result = 0;
        switch (i) {
        case 1:
            result = result + i;
            break;
        case 2:
            result = result + i * 2;
            break;
        case 3:
            result = result + i * 3;
            break;
        }
        default:
           break;
        return result;
    }
```

Comment: +1 for clear/complete answer.  Please mention that providing a default case is (usually/always) a good idea.

Answer (score 11):

Switch statements require `break;` for each case to avoid executing later case statements.

Answer (score 1):

You are forgetting to `**break;** the switch statement.
It should look something like this when you are done:

```
case 1:
    //code
    break;
case 2:
    //code
    break;
```

Also it's always good to include a defualt case:

```
default:
    System.err.println("Something went terribly wrong!");
```

Sorry if this has been posted before, this should fix everything.
I also have a **reason** as to why whats happening is happening:
result is being saved from case 1, and reused with the new value. This is getting that funky error of yours.

Answer (score 0):

The case statement needs a break statement to stop it going into the next case statement.

Also good to have a default case

```
switch (i) {
    case 1:
        result = result + i;
        break;
    case 2:
        result = result + i * 2;
        break;
    case 3:
        result = result + i * 3;
        break;
    default:
        log.error (...);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use "**break;**" to prevent the code from running into the next case automatically.

```
switch (choice)
{
case 0:
  //codes
  break;
case 1:
  //codes
  break;
case 2:
  //codes
  break;
case 3:
  //codes
  break;
}
```